# Promise/A+ with chain then() callbacks use case?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I just started reading about Promise/A+ and wanted to try it for myself.
I added multiple `then()` callbacks and this behavior was surprising.

1) Chaining the then doesn't return the same promise

```
  > new Promise(function(a, r) {a('hello')}).
      then(function(r) { console.log('1', arguments) }).
      then(function(r) { console.log("2", arguments) })
  1 ["hello"]
  2 [undefined]
```

2) Not-chaining works as I expected

```
> p = new Promise(function(a, r) {a('hello')}); 
    p.then(function(r) { console.log('1', arguments) }); 
    p.then(function(r) { console.log("2", arguments) })
1 ["hello"]
2 ["hello"]
```

What is the use case for scenario #1?

Comment: The return value of the `then` method is the [most important promise feature](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572)!

Comment: Instead of asking for example use cases of chaining, let's turn the tables: Give me an example use case for promises, and I'll show you why you need to use chaining for it.

Comment: @Bergi, so, possibly close this question as duplicate?

Comment: @Grundy: I didn't consider it a duplicate. Can you recommend a target?

Comment: @Bergi, i thought about question in your comment above, because seems  here same common question about promises

Comment: @Grundy: Feel free to cast your vote :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aren't promises just callbacks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539815/arent-promises-just-callbacks)

Comment: @Bergi I wasn't saying it isn't useful, I just wanted to know where you would use it. Also I didn't know you were able to return value from the first `then()` to the next one, thats pretty cool.

Answer (score 2):

You just should return value from promise.

```js
new Promise(function(a, r) {a('hello')}).
      then(function(r) { 
        console.log('1', arguments);
        return r; 
      }).
      then(function(r) { console.log("2", arguments) })
```

The returned value passed as argument to callback in `then` function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but I had to read your answer 3 times carefully, can you improve it a bit so others can benefit too?

Comment: @hakunin, i not quite understand how exactly i should improve it, can you a bit explain it?

Comment: "You just should return value from promise." isn't very descriptive. The code formatting is also all over the place and you're missing the output as well.